# player collision not working properly with jump mechanic

Tags: python, pygame

When jumping multiple times, the player can phase through the map. I would assume this is due to the `player.y -= yvel` line but I cant exactly see a work around.

Here is my code, im not sure why the section that stops collision isn't working, it seems as though it should stop all movement that results in collision. Hope this isnt a duplicate, Thanks.

```py
import pygame
import sys

window = pygame.display.set_mode((768,768))

tile_map = []

for i in range(24):
    tile_map.append(pygame.Rect(i*32, 400, 32, 32))

for i in range(12):
    tile_map.append(pygame.Rect(i*32+256, 200, 32, 32))
    
player = pygame.Rect(300,300,32,32)

xvel=0
yvel=0
a = False
d = False
s = False
w = False

space = False

def collision_check(player,tm):
    for t in tm:
        if player.colliderect(t):
            return True
    return False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                a = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                d = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                w = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                s = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                space = True
                
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                a = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                d = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                w = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                s = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                space = False

    window.fill(0)

    yvel += .1

    if space:
        space = False
        yvel -= 5

    if yvel > 5:
        yvel = 5
    if xvel > 5:
        xvel = 5

    if a:
        xvel = -1
    elif d:
        xvel = 1

    if w:
        yvel = -1
    elif s:
        yvel = 1
    
    player.y += yvel
    if collision_check(player, tile_map):
        player.y -= yvel
        yvel = 0
        
    player.x += xvel
    if collision_check(player, tile_map):
        player.x -= xvel
        xvel = 0
            
    pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,0,255),player)

    for t in tile_map:
        pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),t)

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must limit the position of the player rectangle depending on the direction of movement with the bottom or top of the tile with which the player collides. e.g.:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    player.y += yvel
    ti = player.collidelist(tile_map)
    if ti >= 0:
        if yvel < 0:
            player.top = tile_map[ti].bottom  
        else:
            player.bottom = tile_map[ti].top  
        yvel = 0
```